# UILabel not updating programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am attempting to update a UILabel when a user 'Logs In' to my app. I have placed a UILabel onto my Storyboard but it doesn't appear to update, my code is as follows

**ViewController.h**

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{    
     IBOutlet UILabel *followersCount;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *followersCount;

@end
```

I then have an action that connects to a REST API via HTTP and it returns a string, if the string is true a user has logged in, so I want to log that users 'followers' to the label, so I use the code:

```
ViewController.m

followersCount.text = @"Hello World";
```

But I get the default 'Label' text and not the 'Hello World' as expected

Comment: Did you hook up the outlet?  Where is this code being called?  Is that code even being called?

Comment: Show the code you use to check the response.  It stands to reason that if you aren't checking properly then your update will never occur

Comment: The code is being called within a login function, the code must run as a new storyboard is displayed, the code is above that. Jeremy I am unsure as to what you mean by check the response.

Comment: I tried to run 'NSLog(@"%@",self.followersCount.text);' on it and it returned null, why would this be? I expected 'Label'

Comment: @JacobClark It is most likely because you did not hook up the IBOutlet in your storyboard file

Comment: I have, I Cntrl Clicked and Dragged it to the correct Outlet.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the Label Outlet is correctly connected to the Label on you .xib or storyboard file...

If it is, try adding `self` before the label's name:

```
self.followersCount.text = @"Hello World";
```